# Proper convention in java for invoking methods in series

Tags: java, coding-style

What is better programming style in `Java`?
E.g. if I have:

`SomeObject createObject();`

`void process(SomeObject o);`

Is this better?

`process(createObject())` or

`SomeObject o = createObject();

process(o);`

Or something else? Or there is no difference or disadvantage?

Comment: [Do I look like a Guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Comment: second method (2 lines) could make debugging / exception tracking a little easier.

Comment: @assylias:Why what is the difference?

Comment: @Jim If for example both methods can throw `MyException`, the line number alone in the stacktrace will not permit to know which did if they are on the same line. That's admittedly marginal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with any approach but calling the method before passing its result to some other method is good.

So that if there is an exception in the previously called method then you can trace it easily.

Readability is also a plus with this approach and you can also call some other method using the same object reference if there is any.

Answer (score 3):

If you need reference of `SomeObject` somewhere else in curent scope then it is better to use 2nd style:

```
SomeObject o = createObject();
process(o);

// use instance o some other way:
// o.setBase(10);
```

otherwise it is more compact to use 1st style i.e.

```
process(createObject());
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one has the advantage, that you can use the reference to `o` after calling `process(o);`

```
SomeObject o = createObject();
process(o);
// you can use o here, too
```

If you don't need the reference to `o` anymore, `process(createObject());` is fine.

Although readability is better on the second version, I'd probably use the first one.

(Also note, the way you are asking, `createObject()` must be a `static` method)

Answer (score 1):

that depends on requirement, if you are sure SomeObject is not going to be used anywhere else you should use first approach otherwise second is better. I dont think it's much about programming style